# Shield-shaped UI that indicates the limit rotation range of a bone

Tags: interface, bones, constraints, pose-mode

I have a rigged model imported from Daz3D. When I select a bone, sometimes this shield-shaped thing with a red and a blue line shows up.

[image]

It's not a custom shape of the bone:

[image]

I found it's very useful, but I don't know how to make this UI shows up for my own model. Is it something built-in in Blender?

Comment: It's the IK range. In the bone UI panel under IK, you can set the range and changing the numbers should make a similar thing appear in the viewport.

Comment: @NascentSpace Thanks! Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Yeah no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IK range of a bone can be edited by going into pose mode, selecting the bone, opening the bone UI menu panel, and expanding IK. There you can tick on or off the limits, and edit the values.

[image]